# Change Google Workspace primary domain & Google Play Developer ramifications

Tags: g-suite, google

This is tangentially related to the [forced upgrade of free Legacy GSuite accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2855120?product_name=UnuFlow&hl=en&visit_id=637741448986395651-2743528323&rd=1&src=supportwidget0&hl=en). My organization is using Legacy GSuite, but we also went through a rebrand a few years ago and now use a different domain as our primary "public facing" domain, though our Google login remains the original domain we signed up with. Legacy GSuite accounts are not eligible for changing the primary domain, but paid Google Workspace accounts are, so I see this as an opportunity to finally get rid of (though keep aliases for) our legacy domain.

The issue is that we have a Google Play Developer account, and this [help article about the impacts of changing a domain](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2622985?amp;visit_id=637801839811119627-222376840&rd=1&product_name=UnuFlow&product_name=UnuFlow&visit_id=637801839811119627-222376840&rd=2&src=supportwidget0#playdeveloper) says that *"the Google Play Developer account associated with the old user account name is orphaned"*. Then it says:

> **What the user has to do next:**
>
> To maintain access to the apps in the previous Google Play Developer account, the user needs to:
>
> 1. [Create a new Google Play Developer account](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6112435) with the new email address.
> 2. [Request an applications transfer](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/checklist/3294213) for apps in the old account.

Ok, this seems reasonable, except if I use my Google account to log in, and if I switch the primary domain, **will I even be able to log into the "orphaned" account anymore?**

I really wish the documentation was more explicit about this, so I'm hoping someone who has done this before can let me know how it worked out.